# `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate()` not throwing Exception when input parameters are null

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I noticed the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate()` method does not throw an `Exception` when the `String` query passed in is `null`.

I see from the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate(java.lang.String,org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource%5B%5D)) there is no mention of `Exception`s being thrown.

I am referring to the `public int[] batchUpdate(String sql, SqlParameterSource[] batchArgs)` method.

I am asking because the `String` query being passed in is retrieved from a `Hazelcast` cache, so there is a possibility that the query can be `null` if the query doesn't exist in the cache.

I tried experimenting with passing in `null` to the method & the method does not throw any `Exception`, it just returns an `int` value of `0`.

Does this mean I will need to add explicit handling of a `null` object being returned from the `Hazelcast` cache, before inputting a `String` query into the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate()` method?

Wanted to bounce some ideas around & see how other folks use the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate()` method & how they handle passing in a `String` query that is `null`.

Comment: Judging from the code it will throw an exception if it is `null`. So if it isn't throwing you are not passing in `null`. The exception is thrown [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterUtils.java#L84), so when parsing the SQL it will throw the exception.

Comment: If there is no exception I suspect your test is doing something like `batchUpdate(null, new Map[]{});`. Which will run into a short circuit to always return 0. If you pass in values it will throw an exception (not the one pointed to earlier but by the cache lookup).

Comment: @M.Deinum hi Deinum, i just checked & indeed an empty `Array` of `SqlParameterSource` was passed in. Which explains why it short circuit & returned 0. By the way, my apologies, I should've clarified I'm referring to the `public int[] batchUpdate(String sql, SqlParameterSource[] batchArgs)` method

Comment: @M.Deinum just to confirm my understanding, if the executed code was something like `batchUpdate(null, nonEmptyMap)`, then an `Exception` will be thrown?

Comment: Yes it will with any non-empty array of the various implementation of the `batchUpdate`, because in the end they all call the same `bachtUpdate` method. I did discover an issue while creating a test for this, as it doesn't throw the excepted exception but rather one from the cache. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31391